# Automatic ssh processes take up 100% CPU when connecting to the network

Tags: networking, ssh

When booting the machine without the wire cable connected, everything is okay.

Once I connect the wire cable or boot the machine with the cable connected, there are numerous ssh processes coming up.

Although I can use `sudo kill -9` order to kill them, more of them keep coming up and take up all of the memory.

Am I hacked?

[image: The <code>htop</code> result]

Comment: Please [edit] your question and replace the image with the output of `top -c` so we can see more information. And please just copy/paste the output into the question. `top` is just text so there is no reason for an image. You can use the [formatting tools](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting) to format the text as code.